# How to count visible divs between divs

Tags: jquery

How can I count the number of visible `div` that remain once a sibling `div` has been clicked?

For example, if I click 'Element 2' from under the first tag, I want it to hide 'Element 2' and count how many visible siblings remain between the tags so that when there are none left the tag will hide as well

This is my attempt inside the click function, but I am getting an error saying it's not a function:

```js
var visibleLeft = $(this).closest("div.tag").nextUntil("div.tag").find("div.element:visible").length;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag">Tag</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
</div>
<div class="tag">Tag</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: between what tags? what is the expected output/value when Element # is clicked?

Comment: "error saying it's not a function" -> please precise which one is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `.element` elements are siblings, you can just use `siblings()` to determine how many visible elements remain within the current container. If none remain then you can traverse the DOM using `closest()` and `prev()` to hide the required elements:

```js
$('.element').on('click', e => {
  const $target = $(e.target);
  $target.hide();
  
  if ($target.siblings(':visible').length === 0) {
    $target.closest('.container').hide().prev('.tag').hide();
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag">Tag</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
</div>
<div class="tag">Tag</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
</div>
```